# Collapse columns horizontally in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I asked this question in Tex.StackExchange a few days ago [(Collapse table columns to vertical hierarchy)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/286066/collapse-table-columns-to-vertical-hierarchy), but have yet to find a viable solution - possibly because I am trying to automate something rather than manually edit it in LaTeX. In an effort to find a solution, I instead turned to trying to accomplish this in Excel.

I have the following structure in Excel:

```
| Type | Category | Subcategory | Name | Code | Variable | Note      |
|------|----------|-------------|------|------|----------|-----------|
| A    |          |             |      |      |          |           |
|      | A        |             |      |      |          |           |
|      |          | A           |      |      |          |           |
|      |          |             | OneA | one  | one      | Something |
|      |          |             | OneB | One  | One      | Something |
|      |          |             | OneC | One  | One      | Something |
| B    |          |             |      |      |          |           |
|      | A        |             |      |      |          |           |
|      |          | A           |      |      |          |           |
|      |          |             | OneA | One  | One      | Something |
|      |          |             | OneB | One  | One      | Something |
|      | B        |             |      |      |          |           |
|      |          | A           |      |      |          |           |
|      |          |             | OneA | One  | One      | Something |
|      |          |             | OneB | One  | One      | Something |
```

And in a new column, placed between Name and Code - let's call it Combined - I want the contents of all the columns to the left to collapse into this Combined-column, but **with the blank cell's to the left of the first match replaced by the string "\lvl"** (for each of them, the last one followed by a space).

So the expected output would look like this:

```
| Type | Category | Subcategory | Name | Combined          | Code | Variable | Note      |
|------|----------|-------------|------|-------------------|------|----------|-----------|
| A    |          |             |      | A                 |      |          |           |
|      | A        |             |      | \lvl A            |      |          |           |
|      |          | A           |      | \lvl\lvl A        |      |          |           |
|      |          |             | OneA | \lvl\lvl\lvl OneA | one  | one      | Something |
|      |          |             | OneB | \lvl\lvl\lvl OneB | One  | One      | Something |
|      |          |             | OneC | \lvl\lvl\lvl OneC | One  | One      | Something |
| B    |          |             |      | B                 |      |          |           |
|      | A        |             |      | \lvl A            |      |          |           |
|      |          | A           |      | \lvl\lvl A        |      |          |           |
|      |          |             | OneA | \lvl\lvl\lvl OneA | One  | One      | Something |
|      |          |             | OneB | \lvl\lvl\lvl OneA | One  | One      | Something |
|      | B        |             |      | \lvl B            |      |          |           |
|      |          | A           |      | \lvl\lvl A        |      |          |           |
|      |          |             | OneA | \lvl\lvl\lvl OneA | One  | One      | Something |
|      |          |             | OneB | \lvl\lvl\lvl OneB | One  | One      | Something |
```

The purpose is to fit a long list of hierarchical information more easily into a table in LaTeX, where "\lvl" is replaced by a given number of spaces.

In Excel I have tried variations on `concatenate()` and `isblank()`, with the closest solution so far being:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A2),"\lvl",A2) & IF(ISBLANK(B2),"\lvl",B2) & IF(ISBLANK(C2),"\lvl",C2) & IF(ISBLANK(D2),"\lvl",D2)
```

Which I filled down in the Combined-column, but this replaces all blank cells with "\lvl" whereas I only need to fill to the left of the first non-blank one, so I get the expected output shown above. I would greatly prefer not to depend on a macro for this.

Does anyone have a suggestion of how I can achieve this in Excel, through using a common formula/function in the Combined-column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [REPT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/REPT-function-04C4D778-E712-43B4-9C15-D656582BB061) with an approximate [MATCH](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) supplying the *number_times* parameter. An [INDEX](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a)/[MATCH](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) function pair, [CHAR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CHAR-function-BBD249C8-B36E-4A91-8017-1C133F9B837A) and [TRIM function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TRIM-function-410388FA-C5DF-49C6-B16C-9E5630B479F9) can finish it off.

In E2 as,

```
=TRIM(REPT("\lvl", MATCH("zzz", A2:D2)-1)&CHAR(32)&INDEX(A2:D2, MATCH("zzz", A2:D2)))
```

Fill down as necessary.

[image: rept_lvl.]

Comment: That is absolutely superb, exactly what I was looking for!